# React: Search form input not clearing from state by setting state of input to empty array

Tags: reactjs, dom, reset

My form reset button is not clearing the state of the inputs if I use `this.setState({formValues:[]})` in my form reset method. formValues does get reset though by pressing the little x in the input field that appears when setting input property to `type="search"`. My inputs are initially set with my input method here:

```
handleInputChange = (key, value) => {
   const newFormValues = Object.assign({}, this.state.formValues, {[key]: value});
   this.setState({ formValues: newFormValues })
};
```

And here is my form reset method..

```
handleFormReset = () => {
  this.setState({formValues:[]})
  this.setState({contracts:[]})
}
```

Also, the data in the input is not being removed from the DOM. If I set the reset button to `type="reset"` then the DOM clears, but the state still does not clear.

Here is the search form component..

```
<form className="form-inline col-md-12" onReset={this.props.handleFormReset}>

{this.props.labels.map(label => (
  <div className="card border-0 mx-auto" style={styles} key={label.Id}>
       <ul className="list-inline ">
          <span>
            <li>
              <Labels  htmlFor={label.DisplayName} >{label.DisplayName}:</Labels>
            </li>
            <li >
              <Input  
                key={label.Id}
                onChange={(event) => {
                  this.props.handleInputChange(label.DataField, event.target.value)}}
                value={(this.props.newFormValues) }
                type="text"
                maxLength="999"
                style={{height:34}}
                name="value"

                className={"form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2"} 
                id={label.DataField}
              />
            </li> 
          </span>
      </ul>
  </div>
))}

  <div className=" col-sm-12">

  <Button
        style={{ float: "left", marginBottom: 10 }} 
        className="btn btn-success"
        type="submit"
        onClick={this.props.handleFormSubmit}
      >
        Search
      </Button>

      <Help />

      <Button
        style={{ float: "left", marginBottom: 10 }} 
        className="btn btn-secondary"
        onClick={this.props.clear}
      >
        Reset
      </Button>


  </div>

  </form>
```

Here is how the data comes in from the api..
My labels for inputs..

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {Id: 0, DisplayName: "Description", DataValue: "", DataType: "Text", DataField: "IDXT004"}
1: {Id: 1, DisplayName: "Supplier Name", DataValue: "", DataType: "Text", DataField: "IDXT003"}
2: {Id: 2, DisplayName: "Contract #", DataValue: "", DataType: "Number", DataField: "IDXT001"}
3: {Id: 3, DisplayName: "Working Contract ID", DataValue: "", DataType: "Text", DataField: "IDXT002"}
4: {Id: 4, DisplayName: "Sourcing Event", DataValue: "", DataType: "Text", DataField: "IDXT011"}
5: {Id: 5, DisplayName: "Effective Date", DataValue: "", DataType: "Date", DataField: "IDXT005"}
6: {Id: 6, DisplayName: "Expiration Date", DataValue: "", DataType: "Date", DataField: "IDXT006"}
length: 7
```

My results data api..

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {Id: 0, Fields: Array(7), DocImage: {…}}
1: {Id: 1, Fields: Array(7), DocImage: {…}}
length: 2
```

and further broken down..

```
0:
DocImage: {sfKey: 6, sfScanIndex: 6, sfFilename: "2222_1.PDF", sfBatchID: 12898, sfFileUnredact: null, …}
Fields: Array(7)
0: {Id: 0, DisplayName: "Description", DataValue: "2018 Summer Camp CEA between the City, NORD and Infinity Educational Advantage, LLC dba IEANOLA", DataType: "Text", DataField: "IDXT004"}
1: {Id: 1, DisplayName: "Supplier Name", DataValue: "Infinity Educational Advantage, LLC", DataType: "Text", DataField: "IDXT003"}
2: {Id: 2, DisplayName: "Contract #", DataValue: "2222", DataType: "Number", DataField: "IDXT001"}
3: {Id: 3, DisplayName: "Working Contract ID", DataValue: "4321", DataType: "Text", DataField: "IDXT002"}
4: {Id: 4, DisplayName: "Sourcing Event", DataValue: "", DataType: "Text", DataField: "IDXT011"}
5: {Id: 5, DisplayName: "Effective Date", DataValue: "03/09/2018", DataType: "Date", DataField: "IDXT005"}
6: {Id: 6, DisplayName: "Expiration Date", DataValue: "03/06/2019", DataType: "Date", DataField: "IDXT006"}
length: 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `value={this.state.someValue[someProperty]}` on your input element(s).

Setting the object to an empty object *doesn't seem to do the trick*, as React isn't meant to track deep objects. My workaround for this is to set all the values in your deep object to an empty string.

Finally, I also prefer to use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(variable))` as it makes true deep copies. Only caveat would be that it doesn't copy references/functions.

Here is a working example with **multiple** inputs:

```js
let initialState = {
  formValues: {}
}

let apiResponse = [
  {Id: 0, DisplayName: "Description", DataValue: "", DataType: "Text", DataField: "IDXT004"},
  {Id: 1, DisplayName: "Supplier Name", DataValue: "", DataType: "Text", DataField: "IDXT003"},
  {Id: 2, DisplayName: "Contract #", DataValue: "", DataType: "Number", DataField: "IDXT001"},
  {Id: 3, DisplayName: "Working Contract ID", DataValue: "", DataType: "Text", DataField: "IDXT002"},
  {Id: 4, DisplayName: "Sourcing Event", DataValue: "", DataType: "Text", DataField: "IDXT011"},
  {Id: 5, DisplayName: "Effective Date", DataValue: "", DataType: "Date", DataField: "IDXT005"},
  {Id: 6, DisplayName: "Expiration Date", DataValue: "", DataType: "Date", DataField: "IDXT006"},
]

class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = initialState
  }
  
  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    let newValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.formValues))
    newValues[e.target.name] = e.target.value
    this.setState({
      formValues: newValues
    })
  }
  
  clear = () => {
    let emptyValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.formValues))
    Object.keys(emptyValues).forEach(key => emptyValues[key] = "")
    this.setState({
      formValues: emptyValues
    })
  }
  
  clearField = (dataField) => {
    let newValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.formValues))
    newValues[dataField] = ""
    this.setState({
      formValues: newValues
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table><tbody>
        {
          apiResponse.map(res => {
            return (<tr key={res.Id}>
                      <td>{res.DisplayName}</td>
                      <td><input type={res.DataType}
                                 value={this.state.formValues[res.DataField]}
                                 name={res.DataField}
                                 onChange={this.handleInputChange}/></td>
                      <td><button onClick={e => this.clearField(res.DataField)}>X</button></td>
                      <td>&nbsp;State: {this.state.formValues[res.DataField]}</td>
                    </tr>)
          })
        }
        </tbody></table>
        <br/>
        <button onClick={this.clear}>Clear</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render((<App/>), document.getElementById('testing'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="testing">
```

Comment: sorry I should have added that the input value is `value={this.props.newFormValues }`

Comment: just changed my code to work for multiple inputs. What seemed to work best was when I manually emptied values of the object, but keeping the keys.

Comment: Just changed it a bit to programmatically empty the key/value pairs

Comment: ok thanks. Trying to implement in your code. My form is created dynamically from an api, so I can't change the value of each input statically.

Comment: If you add that information to your question along with sample data from your API I can try and help you out further.

Comment: I've made my example dynamically generate inputs and the 'Clear' button still does the trick. Something that's nice about your API's response is that it clarifies the DataType which you seemingly can use for generating your input types.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. Thank you. Yes the api has all data i need well layed out. It would be nice I could clear the state of the inputs as easily as clearing the results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191472/discussion-between-neil-and-denis-j).